# How to programmatically recreate resources done via AWS consoles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to programmatically recreate a bunch of AWS resources that were created/configured manually via AWS consoles.

The AWS consoles do a lot for you.

For example, you can create a Lambda function with an Api-Gateway trigger in about 10 seconds using the AWS console.

The console is doing a lot of magic under the covers, defining and configuring resources such as policies, stages, permissions, models, etc.

In theory, CloudTrail is supposed to allow me to see what exactly is happening under the covers, but it seems to be silent in this case (i.e. Lambda function with Api-Gateway trigger).

I can play hide and seek and do extensive dumps using the CLI to list stages, policies, export api definitions, etc. etc. and look for the differences but is there an easier way? - like some way to trace the REST calls that the console is creating when it does all its magic?

Note: CloudFormer could have helped but it is only half-written software (Hey Amazon!) and only covers about a third of the resources I have defined. Does embracing Cloudformation imply not using these great time-saving consoles?

Comment: use terraform, export your existing infra and then deploy it

Comment: you can import any thing `terraform import resources`

Comment: some resources using terraform local-exec download the lambda code and create one of them, describe gateway and base on properties create on of them. Terraform become power with the combination of local-exec

Comment: Still very far from a 1-click solution. Based on this post and similar, there is a lot of work to do till you get a fully working export. https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/7z7w4u/importing_existing_infrastructure_into_terraform/

The advantage over cli at least is that the import/export both use the same format. With cli, you need to often translate what you get back from CLI get_foobar to a different syntax in the CLI create_foobar.

Answer (score 0):

**CloudFormation and other Infrastructure as code services are there to lessen the clicks you make while using AWS console or any other cloud console to manage your resources.**

But these come in handy when you have to spin up resources which will be having almost the same configurations and software stack.

If you use CloudFormation you will be able to define the policies according to your need, which OS image to use, which stack to install etc. etc. it provides you minute control over your resources.

I suggest if you have to deploy these resources multiple times then create a CloudFormation template and use it.

So, I would suggest that rather than finding a way to recreate the code from your current infrastructure, create a CloudFormation template and use it for future needs.

**If you need something easier than your current flow, this is it, as you just have to write your required configuration once.**

[Hashicorp Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) is also a good alternative to AWS CloudFormation. You can use [Terraforming](http://terraforming.dtan4.net/) to export the current infrastructure into Terraform readable files.